# finding average price of two lots of shares

Tags: recreational-mathematics, average

Sorry, not a math guy, this might be an overly simple question for the lot of you, but it's a calculation that I'll have to do a lot possibly, so please show me the best way to do it. If I have $1265$ shares of XYZ Company that were bought at an average price of $\$3.95$, and $3949$ shares of the same XYZ Company that were bought at $\$5.03$, how can I find the average combined price for the $5214$ ($1265 + 3949$) shares? Thanks.

Comment: What kind of programmer are you? This is arithmetics!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cost of your $1265$ shares was $(1265)(3.95)$.

The cost of your $3949$ shares was $(3949)(5.03)$.

Total cost: $(1265)(3.95)+(3949)(5.03)$.

Total shares: $1265+3949$.

Average cost per share: $\dfrac{(1265)(3.95)+(3949)(5.03)}{1265+3949}$.